# Footer not automatically moving down, and big white space between my article section and the footer of the website when i am in fullscreen

Tags: html, css

I dont know how to properly phrase it, but the footer of my website is not automatically moving down when I extend the article section of my website. Or, the website is not getting bigger when I add content.

The footer is sort of overlapping the content and I want a small white space between my content and the footer. **Better explained below with the pictures**
I included some pictures of the website for better explanation:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

The other problem I have is that whenever I go into fullscreen there will be a big white space between the content of my page and the footer.

Perhaps this fixes itself by resolving the problem above. I included some pictures here as well:

Normal screen:
[image]

In Fullscreen:
[image]

I have no idea what the problem is so I included most of my code, it may be a stupid problem but I have tried a lot and I cant get it to work how I want.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: tahoma;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.stickynav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.stickynav li {
  float: left;
}

.stickynav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stickynav li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.stickynavactive {
  background-color: #000;
}

.posts {
  display: flex;
  background: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}

.posts div {
  border: 1px white solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
}

header {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  border: 10px 0px #454444 solid;
}

footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="stickynav">
    <section>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="stickynavactive" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>


  <div class="posts">
    <div class="box-1">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="footer">
    <footer>
      <a>Footer</a>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is you are using `position: absolute` on the `footer`. `position: absolute` takes the element out of normal document flow - so that's why you are seeing the content getting overlapped by your footer when there is a bunch of content.

It's also the same reason you are seeing the large white space when you are in `fullscreen`. You are basically setting the footer to always be at the bottom of the screen.

#### The problem:

You will not be able to fix all the problems and keep the `footer` at the bottom. Depending on what you think is a bigger issue to resolve, you'll have to choose that one:

1. Remove the `position: absolute` on the footer so it's not always on the bottom.
2. Keep the large amount of white space after your `posts` and keep the footer on the bottom. You can do this by adding bottom padding to the `body` equal to the height of the footer and add `position: relative` to the body, so the `footer` position is relative to the body element.

Here's the first option:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: tahoma;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.stickynav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.stickynav li {
  float: left;
}

.stickynav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stickynav li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.stickynavactive {
  background-color: #000;
}

.posts {
  display: flex;
  background: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}

.posts div {
  border: 1px white solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
}

header {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  border: 10px 0px #454444 solid;
}

footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #000000;
  line-height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="stickynav">
    <section>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="stickynavactive" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>


  <div class="posts">
    <div class="box-1">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis.</p>
      
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="footer">
    <footer>
      <a>Footer</a>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's the second option:

```css
/* ADD THIS SO BODY IS ALWAYS 100% */
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: tahoma;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  /* ADD PADDING, POSITION and BOX-SIZING so the footer can position correctly */
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stickynav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.stickynav li {
  float: left;
}

.stickynav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stickynav li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.stickynavactive {
  background-color: #000;
}

.posts {
  display: flex;
  background: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}

.posts div {
  border: 1px white solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
}

header {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  border: 10px 0px #454444 solid;
}

footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #000000;
  line-height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="stickynav">
    <section>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="stickynavactive" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>


  <div class="posts">
    <div class="box-1">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis.</p>
      <p>Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="footer">
    <footer>
      <a>Footer</a>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option worked very well but is it possible to use media queries to make the footer be position absolute when in fullscreen?

Comment: Yeah, of course! But `fullscreen` doesn't mean anything. You need to have an idea of what pixel width you want it to start at.